# Create form-data subrequest in Nginx JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am writing a special proxy as ACL (Anti Corruption Layer) for some Identity-Service migration. We need to convert JSON body into Form-Data to support old App requests to new service. I would rather to use Njs instead of Lua + couple of packages (Http, json...) for proxying to new gateway via Nginx. I am wondering is there a good way to create a Form Data subrequest in Njs?